# Web site keeps prompting for credentials in IE - but not in Chrome

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I have a web site (forms) and a sub-site (Windows). My problem is with the sub-site with Windows authentication. On Internet Explorer, it intermittently prompts for credentials; when I click Cancel, nothing happens and the user can continue using the site.

This does not happen when I access my site using Chrome.

I have also checked authentication modes and I can confirm that they are properly configured.

Comment: Is the web server joined to a domain and are the computers you are having this problem on joined to the same domain?

Comment: The site is joined to a domain (domain1). And that domain is connected to another domain (domain2) -- I'm only having the issue on domain2 and and outside both domains.